# Regular Expression in redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a data which is being fed in the below format -

`2016-006-011 04:58:22.058`

This is an incorrect date/timestamp format and in order to convert this to a right one as below -

`2016-06-11 04:58:22.058`

I'm trying to achieve this using regex in redshift. Is there a way to remove the additional Zero(0) in the date and month portion using regex. I need something more generic and not tailed for this example alone as date will vary.

Comment: Find `(\d{4}-)\d?(\d{2}-)\d?(\d{2})` Replace `$1$2$3` And you have to define generic date format. Gather together all the date formats used, make a generic regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `regexp_replace()` (see [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html)) should do the trick:

```
select
    regexp_replace(
      '2016-006-011 04:58:22.058'  -- use your date column here instead
    , '\-0([0-9]{2}\-)0([0-9]{2})' -- matches "-006-011", captures "06-" in $1, "11" in $2
    , '-$1$2'                      -- inserts $1 and $2 to give "-06-11"
    )
;
```

And so the result is, as required:

```
     regexp_replace
-------------------------
 2016-06-11 04:58:22.058
(1 row)
```